# Implement an Explecit Garbage Collection Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, garbage-collection

Yesterday i have just heard a lecture about garbage collection in java.["Basics of Garbage Collection"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rp8PvFvSO_c) on You Tube , so i was trying to implement my own garbage collection algorithm.So i just wanted to have any one implemented it.Is there a way to do it ? If yes can  you please help me out with it.
Thanks 
-Sagar S.

Comment: Hey, people ... if you are voting to close, please add at least a comment here, why it is not right.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing your own garbage collection, you also have to implement a complete Java VM, since they are quite woven into each other.

- For the garbage collector to have anything to do, it needs some Java objects.
- For the Java objects to be useful (and to be able to allocate them), you need to execute Java code.

So, if you want to implement this *in Java*, you would have to create a Java virtual machine based on Java.

Good luck :-)

---

If you only want to create a garbage collector for an existing VM, look at the open source ones like OpenJDK, GJC, Apache Harmony. I think they are modularized sufficiently so you could plug in another GC implementation there - you still have to make sure it fits to the memory allocation algorithm, and everything that accesses objects. You would have to implement this in the same language like the VMs themselves, I suppose (so mainly C or C++).

Comment: You dont need full JVM at all, the logic how to collect garbage, copy, mark/sweep, whatever doesn't need any special objects, having reference is enough. Actually sometimes I wonder why optimizations of hotspot are not written in java itself. The garbage collection cannot be written solely in java for real, though (no pointer bit games)